# Xaml binding logic error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind obeservablecollection content from property called LumelauaPikkused to xaml combobox. I am setting datacontext, but for some reson it doenst show any content if I add items to LumelauaPikkused

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VLumelaud"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                Canvas.Left="10" 
                Canvas.Top="200" 
                Cursor="Hand"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Lumelauapikkused}"                          
             >
                <ComboBox.DataContext>
                    <modelsView:LumelauaPikkused/>
                </ComboBox.DataContext>
            </ComboBox>



  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Laenutus.ModelsView
{
    public class LumelauaPikkused
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> _lumelauaPikkused;

        public LumelauaPikkused() 
        {
            this._lumelauaPikkused = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Lumelauapikkused
        {
            get { return _lumelauaPikkused; }
            set { _lumelauaPikkused = value; }
        }


    }
}

 private void LisaVarustusClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        #region LisaLumeLaud


        #endregion

         #region CheckIfTextBoxHasValue
         ///// ADDING LOGIC ////////////
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaMaesuusk.Text))
             {
                  String lisaLumel = _LisaLumelaud.Text;
                  lpp.Lumelauapikkused.Add(lisaLumel);
                  LumelauaPikkused.Add(lisaLumel);
                  Console.WriteLine(" mitu lumelauda " + lpp.Lumelauapikkused.Count);

                 _LisaMaesuusk.Clear();
                  this.DataContext = MSP;
             }

             else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaLumelaud.Text))
             {

                 String lisaSuusk = _LisaMaesuusk.Text;
                 MSP.Maesuusapikkused.Add(lisaSuusk);

                 MaeSuusapikkused.Add(lisaSuusk);
                 Console.WriteLine(" mitu maesuuska " + MSP.Maesuusapikkused.Count);

                 _LisaLumelaud.Clear();
               //  this.DataContext = lpp;
             }
             else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaLumelaud.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_LisaMaesuusk.Text))
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Objekt on lisatud!");
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Sisestage vähemalt üks väärtus");
             }


        #endregion

        // Console.WriteLine("Lumelaudu on: "  + LumelauaPikkused.ToString());

    }
```

// HERE I AM CREATING OBJECT OF THESE CLASSES

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private LumelauaPikkused lpp;
        private Maesuuusapikkused MSP; //MSP = MaeSuusaPikkused
        public static List<string> LumelauaPikkused = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> MaeSuusapikkused = new List<string>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lpp = new LumelauaPikkused();
            MSP = new Maesuuusapikkused();

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have two separate instances of your `DataContext` for binding purposes: the one defined in XAML and the one defined in your constructor/click event code. I would recommend never setting `<X.DataContext>` to a new value like you have in your XAML. I see a lot of new users confused about how the `DataContext` works, so I wrote a blog post for them that you may be interested in reading through : [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/).

Answer (score 0):

Please check names in your code.

Indeed you're inserting an object called `LumelauaPikkused` as ComboBox DataContext, but your class is named `Maesuuusapikkused`.
Moreover you're binding the ComboBox property `ItemsSource` to a property of your DataContext called Lumelauapikkused, but your class has got just one property called `Maesuusapikkused`

**EDIT**

I tried to add some items to the ObservableCollection and I did not find any problem.
I used this code:

```
public class LumelauaPikkused
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _lumelauaPikkused;
    private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;

    public LumelauaPikkused()
    {
        this._lumelauaPikkused = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("One");
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("Two");
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("Three");

        _dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("Four");
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("Five");
        this._lumelauaPikkused.Add("Six");

        _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Lumelauapikkused
    {
        get { return _lumelauaPikkused; }
        set { _lumelauaPikkused = value; }
    }
}
```

I added a `DispatcherTimer` just for adding some elements after a while (maybe in your code you're using a Command in order to add them). As you can see after 20 seconds the ComboBox has 6 items instead of just 3.

**2nd EDIT**

In order to resolve your problem, first af all you have to decide which design architecture you want to use. In your code you used a mix of [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and codebehind pattern.
The first one (the one I prefer) is a little more complicated, but let you test your code in an easier way (since it decouple the UI from your business logic classes).
If you want to use this technique you should understand the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

On the other side if you don't feel confident with MVVM you can use the codebehind in your MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private LumelauaPikkused lpp;
    private Maesuuusapikkused MSP; //MSP = MaeSuusaPikkused
    public static List<string> LumelauaPikkused = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> MaeSuusapikkused = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lpp = new LumelauaPikkused();
        MSP = new Maesuuusapikkused();
        VLumelaud.ItemsSource = lpp.Lumelauapikkused;
    }
    // the rest of your code...
}
```

At the same time you have to remove from your XAML `<modelsView:LumelauaPikkused/>` and the ComboBox ItemsSource binding.

Anyway the most important thing is that you can't mix both MVVM and "codebehind".
I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I have copied the wrong class, the mistakse doesnt lay there :)

Comment: I can succesfully add items to obervablecollection, but I cannot get it displaying in combobox :)

Comment: Can you post the code which you use for adding new items to the ObservableCollection, please?

Comment: I saw your code and I'm afraid you are working on two different instances of the same object. Look at your XAML: if you write `<modelsView:LumelauaPikkused/>`, you are creating a new instace of your LumelauaPikkused class, which is not the same instance you declared in your MainWindow class.

Comment: Okay, Do you have any idea how  can I resolve this problem? :)